# Gold and silver coins in sealed envelopes

Tags: mathematics, strategy, probability

Alice has freely chosen to put either a gold coin or a silver coin in each of an infinite sequence of envelopes numbered 1,2,3,... Bob can open any number of envelopes and check the coins within, provided he leaves at least one envelope untouched. For all the untouched envelopes, Bob then must guess whether it's gold or silver coins within. If he gets all of them correct, Bob wins, otherwise Alice wins. Both seeks to maximize their own winning probabilities.

Clearly, Bob can just leave envelope #1 untouched and randomly guess silver or gold to ensure a 50% winning probability. Can he do better than that?

---

Hint

> Bob can use **the axiom of choice** to his advantage.

Comment: I dont get it. If he leaves 2, he has a 1/4 chance of guessing correctly. If 3, then 1/8, etc... What am i missing?

Comment: Can Alice's strategy be to choose each coin independently and uniformly at random?

Comment: @noedne Yes. But be careful with the definition of independence when it comes to infinitely many coins!

Comment: Oh no, is this going to be a ([rot13](http://rot13.com)) "nkvbz bs pubvpr" thing?

Comment: @Deusovi You're really quick! I don't even need decoding to understand it :p. I was just thinking about giving it as hint. Is that too much for a puzzle?

Comment: @JLee Yeah, something. You will know.

Comment: Very spoiler: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151286

Comment: The answers to the linked question by tehtmi seem to suggest that defining a probability measure in this scenario is dubious. Is your strategy significantly different from what is proposed here?

Comment: @hexomino Once Alice has nailed down her sequence, any choice by Bob either wins or does not.  So there's no problem in defining probability on space of numbers from 1 to N. Bob can even tell Alice what his choice function is before Alice nails down her sequence, same outcome. I believe the comments under the accepted answer in the link have made this point clear, too.

Comment: What if Alice always puts a gold coin in every envelope and Bob goes for probability $2/3$ taking $N=3$. He chooses to be mathematician $0<=i=2<=2$ and finds $M0=M1=0$ i.e.: $M=1$ and $M-1=0$. Would this mean Bob can now guess content of envelope $2=2+0$? How? Theoretically, to speak in terms of probabilities, one would need a probability space (sample space, sigma algebra of events, probability measure on the events) and one would need to match the axioms (like countable disjoint union adds up probabilities). Mapping uniform distribution on ${0,1,2}$ onto this seems not right.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName What does 2=2+0 mean? In your example Bob would not guess the content of envelope 2=2+0, whatever that means.  Instead he now opens envelopes 1 to infinity in the 2nd sequence, determines its representative (say r) by AOC, and guess the content of the 0th envelope to be the 0th entry of r.

Comment: quote from mathoverflow : " and looks at the sequence $\vec u_i$ starting at this $M$. He can deduce the $\approx$-class of the sequence $\vec u_i$, and guesses that $u_{M-1}$ matches the representant. ". $2=2+0$ refers to $i=i+(M-1)$. Guessing the $0th$ element of (sub)row  $2$ that is.

Comment: and element $0$ of sub-sequence $2$ is element $2$ of original sequence following $\vec u_i=(u_{2n+i})_{n\in\mathbb N}$

Comment: sorry I meant $\vec u_i=(u_{3n+i})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as $N=3$

Comment: @Eric just curious ... so, like 'hexomino' also asked, basically : does **(yes/no)** the strategy you have in mind significantly different from matoverflow one linked by 'tehtmi' in comment?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName I've already answered hexomino.

Comment: I'm probably a little out of my depth, but my take is if Alice's strategy is random, we conventionally understand the probability in terms of the product measure. We would get the surprising answer by breaking down our integral on the product space to an iterated integral. Normally this is justified by Fubini, but only for measurable functions which ours (probably) isn't. So, there is a major gap. And, it may be unjustifiable (and this may be expected for a non-measurable fn). Yes, very careful/subtle reformulation can avoid introducing the product measure; maybe hard to judge this threshold.

Comment: For example, in opposite iterated integral, we fix a choice of Bob, and supposing Alice is uniform, we could try to argue that if Alice swaps the evelope that Bob guesses, her distribution doesn't change. (In normal circumstances, this kind of argument is probably reasonable, though here it probably has issues due to non-measurability.) So, Alice has 1/2 chance of winning. Given an non-measurable function, we shouldn't be surprised to get a different answer for a different order of iteration (and maybe there is a better counterexample without so much hand waving).

Comment: @tehtmi According to the definition of independence on Wikipedia, when we say a set of infinitely many random variables is independent, what we mean is that any finite subset of it is independent. So if you believe in AOC and you believe in an infinite set where every r.v. is independent of ALL the others, you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for comments. Regarding mathoverflow question #151286 : I admit I do not understand 'Alexander Pruss' final answer part where Zorn is mentioned, but the OP by 'Denis' argued: "At most one mathematician will be wrong: the one who has the number $i$ with $M_i$ maximal.". I wonder: can't there be multiple mathematicians having such $i$ with $M_i$ maximal? Like when Alice's strategy is to always put a gold coin in  every envelope? Sorry if this comment does not affect final (still to be found by someone) answer here.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Yes that can happen, it doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: My point then was to state Bob's choice of being mathematician $0<=i<=1$ could be any $i$... the $i$'th element of the original un-split intact sequence would be no better than a fair 50% guess. However: this adheres to mathoverflow question #151286 OP and **not** to its approved answer (which, for me, needs more understanding for the simple case $N=3$ and $i=$any). @Eric perhap you could tease audience with an answer or someone (maybe myself :-) could start a bounty.